# Get username without requiring it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

There's an interesting problem I'm facing as an educator. I want to collect user names in a form, but when I do that, it automatically enables students to email themselves a copy of their response.

I believe there's a way to somehow poll who's responded. When you enable the "one response per user" option, it doesn't require a stored user name. I know the information is out there somewhere - I just don't know how to get to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I neglected to be specific about the coding aspect - apologies. I'm generating the form programmatically, and wanted to know if the information is stored somewhere in the response when the one-response-per-person option is enabled. After more digging, it appears that the easiest way to deal with this is to use an extension to handle disabling the email option.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Another option would be to check out the [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange forum.

Comment: you cant get to the email unless you enable the option you already found.

Comment: i think its boundary on-topic because its about a part of apps-script. it isnt about code but its about a tool primarily used for programming on gas.

Answer (score 0):

you cant get the user email unless you enable that option like you mentioned. yes google might internally know who you are if you were already logged-in but its not perfect because using chrome incognito mode for example would not detect the email.

one way I can think is to:

1) with apps script generate an array of all student emails and a random password. dump to a private spreadsheet and use as your database for the next script.

2) in your forms, ask first as a form question the custom username and password.

3) on another script you can generate form urls with prefilled usernames and passwords and email each student their own custom form url.

when the student opens the form to respond, the username and password would be prefilled already.

not perfect but a malicious user would need to hack the email and if they can hack their email then they could also impersonate the user logged-in.